# Leaflet: How to specifiy order of overlays in the layers control?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

**Is it possible to order overlays within the layers control?**

Here's my issue. When I do this with my overlays:

```
var overlays = {
"Apples": apples,
"Bananas": bananas,
"Peaches": peaches
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

Leaflet adds the overlays to the layer control on the map in a random fashion (due to iteration):

```
- Bananas
- Apples
- Peaches
```

Is it possible to specificy the order I want to show the overlays? *(In my case, I'd like to have it alphabetical. *Also, I am using the Mapbox API)*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if Mapbox API has changed the default Layers Control code / behaviour, but the latter does not provide a 100% reliable way of displaying overlays in a specific order. See that [post](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/422#issuecomment-144186036) for details.

The explanation is that the Layers Control iterates overlays by their "stamp" (a unique identifying integer that is created using `L.stamp(myLayer)`). Depending on your type of layer, this stamp is assigned automatically but at different moments.

You can force its creation right after having instantiated your layer. For example in your case:

```js
var apples = L.layerGroup();
L.stamp(apples);

var bananas = L.layerGroup();
L.stamp(bananas);

var peaches = L.layerGroup();
L.stamp(peaches);
```

Unfortunately the order of iteration is not guaranteed as per JS spec, hence the impossibility to have a 100% reliability in this behaviour.

That being said, in all browsers I have tested, the order is in accordance with the natural number order, so as of today, this trick works.

If you want more confidence, you should look for Control plugins that explicitly provide you with the functionality to specify manually the order of listing.

Comment: Perfect! Worked great!

Comment: Just an observation: This doesn't seem to work in FireFox (38.2.1), but Chrome and IE are fine.

Comment: Damn I would be interested to see it iterating in a different order! Please can you make a jsfiddle to show me? My Firefox still iterates in normal number order (http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/22/). Which version of FF and OS do you have?

Comment: I have about 28+ variables that are being toggled, so I will try to see how I can port over an example. Will post soon.